# CakePHP2 created plugin not found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

When open page I get error:

> Plugin Authority could not be found.
>
> Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

I created new plugin under `app/Plugin` with this structure:

[image]

Green color represents newly created files.

I created this plugin the same way all other plugins are made (white directories).
My route to page is:

```
Router::connect('/authority', array('plugin'=>'Authority', 'controller' => 'Authority', 'action' => 'index'));
```

My `routes.php` include this line:

```
CakePlugin::routes();
```

This is example of some other route that is working:

```
Router::connect('/login', array('plugin' => 'users','controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
```

Here are some other files from the plugin:

> AuthorityAppController.php

```
<?php
class AuthorityAppController extends AppController {

}
```

> AuthorityController.php

```
<?php
class AuthorityController extends AuthorityAppController {

  public function index(){

  }

}
```

> AuthorityAppModel.php

```
<?php
class AuthorityAppModel extends AppModel {

}
```

And this is my bootstrap line of code for activating plugins:

> bootstrap.php

```
CakePlugin::loadAll(array( 'routes' => true ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the cache. I cleared `tmp` directory and it works now.

```
cd app/tmp
rm -rf *
```